# gunicorn + django - https requests get stuck

Tags: django, gunicorn

I use gunicorn as HTTP server and Django as the app behind. I didn't set up SSL at all. When I make a https request to my app the process seems to be waiting for something and the request is stucked. Since the app runs in a single thread and single worker other requests get blocked until I cancel my https request.

How can I forbid https at all in gunicorn? I don't/can't use nginx at all to filter incoming requests.

Comment: I don't understand, when you start gunicorn you bind a specific port to your process. How can an HTTPS request (port 443) be processed by your gunicorn server in the first place if you didn't bind port 443 to it?

Comment: I do bind it to 8000 because it runst inside docker container.

Comment: Yes, but explain then how a request on port 443 can reach your gunicorn server that's listening to port 8000. Somewhere you must have a proxy server doing that. Disable that and 443 requests will not reach your gunicorn server.

Comment: I don't mess with 443 at all. I just ping my container via curl like `curl https://127.0.0.1:8000` which reaches the container.